# PHP-FPM docker container stops responding after a while (in some cases weeks) on Digital Ocean with Caddy

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, caddy

I have 3 different Ubuntu droplets with Docker on Digital Ocean. They are all running Caddy as proxy with 2 of them using PHP-FPM and 1 using PHP-FPM Alpine.

After the server has been running a while, sometimes a few days, sometimes 3-4 weeks, the request stops responding.

All has the same type of problem.

I can SSH into the droplet. The caddy seems to be running all fine. I can access everything through caddy that is not the PHP.

The interessting part from the Caddy Docker log is this:

```
{
  "level": "error",
  "logger": "http.log.error",
  "msg": "dialing backend: dial tcp 172.30.0.3:9000: i/o timeout",
  "duration": 3.014910236,
  "status": 502,
  "err_id": "j14574vxr",
  "err_trace": "reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:1196)"
}
```

If I do a `docker logs -f PHP_CONTAINER` all I can see is a valid request from the time before PHP stopped responding.

If i restart only the PHP container it starts working again. The strange part is that if I ONLY do a restart of CADDY container it will also start working.

I didn't seem to have this problem with NGINX earlier. So I my initial thought was that CADDY was the problem. But I do get connection to other services on the same Docker server. For instance PHP-FPM service doesn't respond, but my phpMyAdmin service is still working.

The caddy file is like this:

```
mydomain.com {
    root * /var/www/public
    php_fastcgi /* php:9000
    file_server
}
```

The PHP-FPM Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM php:8.1.6-fpm

ARG user
ARG uid

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
r
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

I have tried multiple versions of PHP-FPM, it still happening.

For my WordPress site, using the FPM-Alpine version, I basically use the same Dockerfile as this (some smaller modifications only)
https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/latest/php8.1/fpm-alpine/Dockerfile

Does anyone has tips to what I can try to figure out why this error keeps happening.

UPDATE 14th of June 2023.
Still getting this issue. I had one droplet running well a couple of months, but are now failing every day. I added NGINX alongside with CADDY, but once the server stop responding both caddy and nginx won't respond. NGINX says: "502 Bad Gateway". The NGINX log says:

`2023/06/14 12:39:45 [error] 22#22: *49 connect() failed (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: MY_IP_ADDRESS_HIDDEN, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.0.3:9000", host: "my_hidden_domain.com:8075", referrer: "http://my_hidden_domain.com:8075/".`

I can see that PHP is running. And again, if I only restart caddy it works again, so my guess is that the connection to fastcgi is being blocked.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the container's networks? It feels like something's going on with the network they're using to talk.

Comment: I haven't tried resetting the network. Trying to figure out how. For what I can see, caddy and php is on the same subnet with different IP-addresses. I can ping both IP-addresses inside Ubuntu terminal. Trying to curl PHP container ip-address with port 9000 on a server where everything is alright is responding "Recv failure: connection reset by peer". Trying the one where traffic is down, I get error: «Failed to connect to 172.30.0.3 port 9000: Connection timed out».

Comment: I tried to disconnect php from network and reconnect it again. Still same error. I don't want to restart the container until I tried to find the reason to why it stops.

Comment: I removed the network and added it back again and connected each container. Caddy and phpMyAdmin work again, but PHP-FPM has the same problem. Caddy still says: «dialing backend: dial tcp 172.31.0.4:9000: i/o timeout»

Comment: Hey! Have you identified the cause of this issue? I'm facing similar problems working with `caddy:2-alpine` and `wordpress:6-php8.2-fpm-alpine` images. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure, but it sure has gotten better with these .ini settings for PHP. Make sure to set them according to your system/server. Also remove comma:


max_execution_time=150, request_terminate_timeout=150s, post_max_size=64M, upload_max_filesize=64M, pm=dynamic, pm.max_children=17, pm.start_servers=4, pm.min_spare_servers=4, pm.max_spare_servers=12, pm.process_idle_timeout=10s, pm.max_requests=200.

Comment: I still have this issue. I had a wordpress site that worked perfectly for months. Then now, suddenly, I get the exact same problem - and it occurs almost everyday. If I only restart Caddy "docker restart wp_caddy" or the php "docker restart wp_php", it works again. Though the phpmyadmin container through caddy works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue, not quite the same setup but exact same symptoms. My PHP image is 7.4-fpm (non alpine). My other containers are nginx, mysql. Everything is ok. Only the PHP container needs restart like every 12 hours. I am not sure whether it is because of the broken image, or the pm.max_children=4.